# Addsubview in touchesBegan, subview must intercept touchesMoved

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitouch

I have a `UICollectionView` in my `UIViewController`. When a `touchesBegan` is call on one of the `UICollectionViewCell` I create a `UIView` added to the `UIViewController.view`, at the exactly frame of the `UICollectionViewCell` (A kind of overlay).

That I would like, is instead of the `touchesMoved` is called in the `UICollectionView`, it must be called in my new `UIView`.

To resume, I juste want to make a kind of drag & drop with the view created above the `UICollectionViewCell`.

To do this, I have tried to disable userinteraction with no success.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: y touches began call on uicollectionview cell ? y can;t u use did select item ?

Comment: @Mr.T the didselectitem is called when touch up of the cell, it's to late for the drag and drop.

Comment: You can use the didHighlightItem methods to detect when a cell is tapped down on